# How do I create text file and file name contains the creation date in bash?

Tags: bash, shell-script, files

I need a bash script for new text files generation in a folder with an interval of a few seconds and stops after a specified time. The content does not matter, the filename should contain the creation date.
like

```
2021-03-23_13_44_21.txt
2021-03-23_13_44_22.txt
2021-03-23_13_44_23.txt
```

I finished a bash script for files generation with creation date. But the file type is unknown.
This is my code

```
data_dir="${1}"
duration=${2}
file_name=$(date "+%F_%T").txt

cd "${data_dir}"

start_time=$(date +%s)
while ((($(date +%s)-start_time)<=duration))
do
    : > $(date "+%F_%T")  #Year month day time
    printf -v file_name '%s.txt' "$(date "+%F_%T")"
done

touch "$file_name"
```

my result is

```
2021-03-23_134419
2021-03-23_134420
2021-03-23_134421
2021-03-23_134421.txt
```

I have no ideas about this problem.

Comment: What's the purpose of the `:` line in the loop? And why do you do `touch` _outside_ the loop (which only uses the last value that `file_name` got in the loop)?

Comment: This looks like a locale issue. What do you see with this: `date "+%F_%T" | od -c`. Is it different when you do `LC_ALL=C date "+%F_%T" | od -c`?